# Validation for Integer field

Tags: validation, jsf, integer

I have a JSF 1.0 web application. I am using backing bean for validation. I have an `Integer` field. How can I validate that field? Typecast of object value to string is not working. Is there any converter? I would like to store the data as `Integer` type in my model.

Comment: What are you using so far? What bean container are you using? What does your existing code look like? What kind of constraints on the field? Is it just supposed to be an integer or is there a range? With no range checking, you don't need validation -- JSF will convert the string to an integer if the backing bean property is an integer.

Comment: Thank you Bob,I am just now implementing the validation for some fields in the form. Managed bean is being used. i have done for all the fields having string type.struggling to do for Integer type.

Comment: public void validateEmail(FacesContext context, 
                          UIComponent toValidate,
                          Object value) {
    String email = (String) value;

    if (email.indexOf('@') == -1) {
       ((UIInput)toValidate).setValid(false);

        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Invalid Email");
        context.addMessage(toValidate.getClientId(context), message);
    }

}             @ eg of what i am using. the string is typecasted,how can i do it similar for Integer type.